# jQuery-Airline Ticket Price Calculation

Tags: jquery

User selects the departure and arrival. For example, from Australia to Singapore, the price for adult ticket is $100, child is charged 80% from adult price, and infant is charged 10% from adult price. Then, the total price will be displayed at the bottom.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            Full Name:
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name"><br>
            Passport/Identification Card:
            <input type="text" id="ic" placeholder="number"><br>
            Phone Number:
            <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="phone number"><br>
            Email Address:
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br>
            Departing:
            <select name="depart" id="dropDest">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
               <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>

            </select>
            <br>
            Arriving:
            <select name="arrive" id="Arrive">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
               <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            Number of Adult:
            <input type="number" id="Adult">
            <br>
             Number Child:
            <input type="number" id="Child">
            <br>
            Number of  Infant:
            <input type="number" id="Infant">
            <br>Trip type: <br />
            Round Trip
            <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
            One way
            <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="start">Departure Date</label>
                <input type="date" id="start" name="trip" value="" min="" max="2030-12-31" />
            </div>
            <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
                <label for="end">Return Date</label>
                <input type="date" id="yes" name="trip" value="" min="" max="2030-12-31" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Jquery that will display the output from the text input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var name = $("#txtName").val();
    var passport = $("#ic").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var departing = $("#dropDest").val();
    var arriving = $("#Arrive").val();
    var noAdult = $("#Adult").val();        
var noChild = $("#Child").val();
    var noInfant = $("#Infant").val();
    var departure = $("#start").val();
    var Return = $("#yes").val();

    var text ="Full Name: " + name + "<br/>Passport Number: " + passport + "<br/>Phone Number: " + phone + "<br/>Email Address: " + email + "<br/>Departing: " + departing + "<br/>Arriving: " + arriving + "<br/>No of Adult: " + noAdult +"<br/>No of Child: " + noChild + "<br/>No of Infant: " + noInfant + "<br/>Departure Date: " + departure + "<br/>Return Date: " + Return;

    $("#result").html(text);
    return false;
});
```

[My JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7ewshoat/1/)

How can I do the calculation? Thank you.

Comment: if number of adult was 5, if the child was only one then the ticket of child was 400$,

Comment: Nope not like that. The adult ticket costs $100. Therefore, the child ticket is just $80 while ticket for infants costs just $10. Suppose the number of adult is 5, and only one child with them, the total cost of ticket will be $580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var adult = parseInt($('#Adult').val());
        var child = parseInt($('#Child').val());
        var infant = parseInt($('#Infant').val());

        var totalAdult = adult*100;
        var totalChild = (child*100)*0.8;
        var totalInfant =  (infant*100)*0.1;

        totalFightCost = parseInt(totalAdult)+parseInt(totalInfant)+parseInt(totalChild);

        alert(totalFightCost);

    });
```